# group by SQL properly

Tags: sql

I have a table that stores the names and values on separate rows for work that takes place on a location like this below.

```
+--------+------------+--------+------------+----------+
| WorkID | Attribute  | Value  |  Chagedby  |   Date   |
+--------+------------+--------+------------+----------+
|      1 | Unit Name  | Unit 1 | John Smith | Jan-2018 |
|      1 | Unit Value | OK     | John Smith | Jan-2018 |
|      2 | Unit Name  | Unit 2 | John Smith | Feb-2018 |
|      2 | Unit Value | Not Ok | John Smith | Feb-2018 |
|      3 | Unit Name  | Unit 3 | John Smith | Mar-2018 |
|      3 | Unit Value | OK     | John Smith | Mar-2018 |
+--------+------------+--------+------------+----------+
```

I have a query on this table that joins other tables and the output looks like this.

```
+--------+--------------+--------------------+----------------------+------------+----------+
| WorkID |   Location   | Value when unit ID | Value when ok/not ok |  Chagedby  |   Date   |
+--------+--------------+--------------------+----------------------+------------+----------+
|      1 | Springfield  | Unit 1             | NULL                 | John Smith | Jan-2018 |
|      1 | Springfield  | NULL               | OK                   | John Smith | Jan-2018 |
|      2 | Shelbyville  | Unit 2             | NULL                 | John Smith | Feb-2018 |
|      2 | Shelbyville  | NULL               | Not Ok               | John Smith | Feb-2018 |
|      3 | Capital City | Unit 3             | NULL                 | John Smith | Mar-2018 |
|      3 | Capital City | NULL               | OK                   | John Smith | Mar-2018 |
+--------+--------------+--------------------+----------------------+------------+----------+
```

what ends up happneing is the attribute "Value" is either the Name of my unit or the result of the test. how do i group this so it shows up on the same line.

```
+--------+--------------+--------------------+----------------------+------------+----------+
| WorkID |   Location   | Value when unit ID | Value when ok/not ok |  Chagedby  |   Date   |
+--------+--------------+--------------------+----------------------+------------+----------+
|      1 | Springfield  | Unit 1             | OK                   | John Smith | Jan-2018 |
|      2 | Shelbyville  | Unit 2             | Not OK               | John Smith | Feb-2018 |
|      3 | Capital City | Unit 3             | OK                   | John Smith | Mar-2018 |
+--------+--------------+--------------------+----------------------+------------+----------+
```

Comment: Edit your question and (1) show the query you are using.  (2) tag with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would join the table to itself, filtering once by name, the other one by value, as in:

```
select
    a.workid,
    a.value as name,
    v.value as value,
    a.changedby,
    a.date
  from my_table a
  left join my_table v on a.workid = v.workid
  where a.attribute = 'Unit Name'
    and v.attribute = 'Unit Value'
```

I added a `left join` to include attributes that don't have a value yet.